# SQL Query ORACLE select all devices ordered from most expensive ones to cheapest

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I have this db structure [db structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvPEB.png)
and I need to select all devices ordered from most expensive ones to cheapest. Output should
have serial number, maker, price, type but the maker attribute is on the product table and I don't know how to add it to query. The attribute in comon with all tables is model.
Tables info:

```
table Laptop (serial_number varchar(50),
 model,
 price,
 speed,
 ram,
 hd,
 screen,
 CONSTRAINT laptop_pk PRIMARY KEY (serial_number),
 CONSTRAINT laptop_2_product_fk
 FOREIGN KEY (model)
 REFERENCES Product(model)); 

table Product (model varchar(50),
 maker,
 type,
 CONSTRAINT product_pk PRIMARY KEY (model));

table Printer (serial_number varchar(50),
 model,
 price,
 color,
 type,
 CONSTRAINT printer_pk PRIMARY KEY (serial_number),
 CONSTRAINT printer_2_product_fk
 FOREIGN KEY (model)
 REFERENCES Product(model));

table PC (serial_number varchar(50),
 model,
 price,
 speed,
 ram,
 hd,
 cd,
 CONSTRAINT pc_pk PRIMARY KEY (serial_number),
 CONSTRAINT pc_2_product_fk
 FOREIGN KEY (model)
 REFERENCES Product(model));

table Storage (storage_id varchar(50),
 model,
 serial_number,
 transfered_to);
```

I try this but of course this just give me the model and I need serial number, maker, price and type.
I'm trying this on livesql.

```
WITH MAX
AS (
    SELECT model, price FROM PC
    UNION 
    SELECT model, price FROM Laptop
    UNION 
    SELECT model, price FROM printer
  
)

SELECT model FROM MAX
WHERE price = (
    SELECT MAX(price) 
    FROM MAX
)
```

Comment: Please don’t link to images. Update your question to provide some sample data, as editable text, and the result you want to achieve based on that sample data

Answer (score 0):

You must join the all tables and select the wanted columns

```
WITH MAX
AS (
    SELECT PC.model,st.serial_number, pr.maker, p.rtype, PC.price 
  FROM PC INNER JOIN Product pr ON PC.model = pr.model
  INNER JOIN  Storage st ON PC.model = st.model
    UNION 
    SELECT Laptop.model ,st.serial_number, pr.maker, p.rtype, Laptop.price 
  FROM Laptop INNER JOIN Product pr ON Laptop.model = pr.model
  INNER JOIN  Storage st ON Laptop.model = st.model 
    UNION 
    SELECT printer.model,st.serial_number, pr.maker, p.rtype, printer.price 
  FROM printer INNER JOIN Product pr ON Laptop.model = pr.model
  INNER JOIN  Storage st ON printer.model = st.model 
  
)

SELECT model,serial_number, maker, rtype, price 
FROM MAX
WHERE price = (
    SELECT MAX(price) 
    FROM MAX
)
ORDER BY price
```